# C# Multiple Generic Parameters into single concrete type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstraction

I am little stuck with achieving something with multiple generic parameters. I have a service interface which will take a messagecontext interface as input to method.

```
 public interface IService<T,U> where T : IMessageContext<U>
 {
    void ExecuteJob(T data);

    bool CancelJob();
 }
```

Then an abtract class which implements the interface.

```
public abstract class AbstractService<T,U> : IService<T,U> where T: IMessageContext<U>
{

    public virtual bool CancelJob()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public abstract void ExecuteJob(T data);
}
```

The `IMessage` interface and default implementation is as shown below

```
public interface IMessageContext<U>
{
    U Data { get; set; }
}

public class DefaultMessageContext : IMessageContext<string>
{
    public string Data { get ; set; }
}
```

In this case, if we inherit the `AbstractService` class, it would be like below with the Generic parameters for T as `DefaultMessageContext` & U as `string`

```
public class ConcereteService : AbstractService<DefaultMessageContext,string>
{

    public override void ExecuteJob(DefaultMessageContext data)
    {
        //Execute the job
    }
}
```

Is there a way where I can just only mention the type for T as `DefaultMessageContext` as the type of U is already set in the class while implementing `IMessageContext`

**Something like this**

```
public class ConcereteService : AbstractNewService<DefaultMessageContext>
{

    public override void ExecuteJob(DefaultMessageContext data)
    {
        //Execute the job
    }
}
```

I could introduce another layer of abstraction where the type of U is set as string and only keep T open for implementation like `AbstractStringService<T> : AbstractService<T,string>`.  But I don't want to do that.

Is there any other way to achieve it.

Comment: Does `AbstractService` _need_ to know the data type of `IMessageContext`? Surely the concrete services will know this from the concrete context type. Could you derive `IMessageContext<U>` from a non-generic base `IMessageContext`, and then your service is just `IService<T> where T : IMessageContext`?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer It did cross my mind to derive `IMessageContext<U>` from non-generic type of `IMessageContext`. But wasn't sure if I should take that route. It doesn't then make sure that my message context will have a Data Property in it. Wouldn't it become a problem at Concrete layer

Comment: It only becomes a problem if your service needs to access the Data property, hence my question

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer Yes it need to.. That's the idea.. The data required to process in the service will be supplied through the property

Comment: OK, in that case does it really need to know all the concrete context types, or do you just need specialisation for the context data types? ie, could you just do `IService<U> : IMessageContext<U>`

Comment: I would say I just need specialization for the context data types. Starting to think may be I am making it too complicated. I could just do away with `IMessageContext<U>` altogether and change `IService<T>`  so that `T` is just constrained to being a `class`. 
`public interface IQueueService<T> where T : class`